# Failure registering instances with ELB: InvalidInstance: InvalidInstance found in [i-06ff41a77dfb5349d]

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

How to fix a code to solve this issue? I had two instances id in a code but it should be passing from variables.
After ELB is run I should be able to run dns name of ELB to open for example view of my wordpress instance in browser. How to fix it? The rest of code works fine.
....................................................................................................

```
resource "aws_vpc" "myvpc"{
 cidr_block = "192.168.0.0/16"
 instance_tenancy = "default"
 enable_dns_hostnames = true
 tags = {
 Name = "newvpc"
 }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "firstsubnet"{
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.myvpc.id
  cidr_block = "192.168.1.0/24"
  availability_zone = "${var.availability_zone1}"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
  tags = {
    Name = "public_subnet"
  }
}


resource "aws_subnet" "secondsubnet"{
 vpc_id = aws_vpc.myvpc.id
 cidr_block = "192.168.2.0/24"
 availability_zone = "${var.availability_zone2}"
 tags = {
 Name = "private_subnet"
 }
}



resource "aws_instance" "wp" {
 ami = "ami-07d9160fa81ccffb5"
 instance_type = "t2.micro"
 vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.mysc1.id}"]
 subnet_id = aws_subnet.firstsubnet.id
 key_name = "MyKey"
 user_data = "${file("wordpress.sh")}"
 tags = {
 Name = "wordpress"
 }
 connection {
 type = "ssh"
 user = "ec2-user"
 private_key = file("./MyKey.pem")
 host = aws_instance.wp.public_ip
 }
   
}



module "asg" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/autoscaling/aws"
  version = "~> 3.0"
  
  name = "service"

  # Launch configuration
  lc_name = "example-lc"

  image_id        = "ami-ebd02392"
  instance_type   = "t2.micro"
  security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.mysc1.id}"]

  ebs_block_device = [
    {
      device_name           = "/dev/xvdz"
      volume_type           = "gp2"
      volume_size           = "50"
      delete_on_termination = true
    },
  ]

  root_block_device = [
    {
      volume_size = "50"
      volume_type = "gp2"
    },
  ]

  # Auto scaling group
  asg_name                  = "example-asg"
  vpc_zone_identifier       = ["${aws_subnet.firstsubnet.id}", "${aws_subnet.secondsubnet.id}"]
  health_check_type         = "EC2"
  min_size                  = 0
  max_size                  = 2
  desired_capacity          = 2
  wait_for_capacity_timeout = 0

  tags = [
    {
      key                 = "Environment"
      value               = "dev"
      propagate_at_launch = true
    },
    {
      key                 = "Project"
      value               = "megasecret"
      propagate_at_launch = true
    },
  ]

  tags_as_map = {
    extra_tag1 = "extra_value1"
    extra_tag2 = "extra_value2"
  }
}



module "elb_http" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/elb/aws"
  version = "~> 2.0"

  name = "elb-example"

  subnets         = ["${aws_subnet.firstsubnet.id}", "${aws_subnet.secondsubnet.id}"]
  security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.mysc1.id}"]
  internal        = false

  listener = [
    {
      instance_port     = "80"
      instance_protocol = "HTTP"
      lb_port           = "80"
      lb_protocol       = "HTTP"
    },
    {
      instance_port     = "8080"
      instance_protocol = "http"
      lb_port           = "8080"
      lb_protocol       = "http"
      #ssl_certificate_id = "arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:235367859451:certificate/6c270328-2cd5-4b2d-8dfd-ae8d0004ad31"
    },
  ]

  health_check = {
    target              = "HTTP:80/"
    interval            = 30
    healthy_threshold   = 2
    unhealthy_threshold = 2
    timeout             = 5
  }

 # // ELB attachments
 number_of_instances = 2
 instances           = ["i-06ff41a77dfb5349d", "i-4906ff41a77dfb53d"]

  tags = {
    Owner       = "user"
    Environment = "dev"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to achieve. The code does not make much sense sadly. You create ASG which is not used, then you have standalone wordpress instance and classic load balancer (elb) for two instances? Which two instances? You have only one wordpress instance, not two?

Comment: I am trying to achive this kind of service that after this one is deployed I want to use dns name of ELB in browser to view one of the two instances of wordpress. Now I am able to view from my instance wordpress to view first page and this is fine. 

I want to fix this ASG to achieve this and pass instances ID behind ELB.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use classic load balancer (ELB) with your ASG, you have to **interconnect** them. This means, that you do not need explicitly specify `instances` in your `elb_http` module.

This is done by setting [load_balancers](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/autoscaling_group#load_balancers) attribute of your `asg` module:

```
module "asg" {

 # other attributes

 load_balancers  = [module.elb_http.this_elb_id]

}
```

This will ensure that instance created by ASG will be **automatically registered** with ASG.

Full example of such a setup is:

- [Auto Scaling Group with ELB example](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-autoscaling/tree/master/examples/asg_elb)

Comment: why there aren't instance mysql and wordpress behind elb but service instances?

Comment: @TJstock Hi. You have to set it all up through UserData in your autoscaling group. My answer shows how to deal with the issue posted, which is the InvalidInstances error. You could make new question specific to setting up wordpress and databases for your asg, if you want.

Comment: Ok then, I will do it